# HD FLV video playing slow

Tags: ffmpeg, flv

I have a few videos which I have captured from a Live Streaming Media Server and they are in FLV Format. Now, the problem is, though the videos are captured completely but when I play them in VLC Media Player, they play very slowly, almost frame by frame like a slideshow.

Here are the details of the Video codec, audio codec, bitrate and other details of the video which I got using ffmpeg:

```
[flv @ 0051e9a0] Invalid keyframes object, skipping.
[flv @ 0051e9a0] Keyframe index parsing failed
Input #0, flv, from 'tofix.flv':
  Metadata:
    audiodelay      : 0
    audiosize       : 6607344
    canSeekToEnd    : false
    datasize        : 271773993
    hasAudio        : true
    hasCuePoints    : false
    hasKeyframes    : true
    hasMetadata     : true
    hasVideo        : true
    lastkeyframetimestamp: 424
    lasttimestamp   : 425
    metadatacreator : inlet media FLVTool2 v1.0.6 - http://www.inlet-media.de/fl
vtool2
    videosize       : 265143027
  Duration: 00:07:04.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1903 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 960x540, 5112 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k
 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 112 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

The bit rate is 1903 kbps and the codec is flv1.

I also captured some other videos from the server which are in h.264 codec with a bit rate of 563 kbps and they play properly.

Is there a way I can play these high definition FLV files in my media player smoothly?

It would be great if this is possible.

I have tried converting the FLV video to AVI using ffmpeg, however, the issue still remains.

Answer (score 1):

Your container says 1 fps [1 tbn] so it is playing at 1 fps. Remux them with 29.97 and also fix your capture mechanism.
Question is more fit for Stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mentioned 1 tbn, but the output I have given says, 1K tbn instead, which would mean, 1000 tbn? Also, I have another video captured from the same server and it plays properly. It has values, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc. The only difference I could see was in value of tbc. How do I remux using ffmpeg as you suggested. Could you please give a command line example to do it? I was not sure where to post this question, since I already saw some questions related to ffmpeg asked here, I posted my question on this site. Your help would be appreciated.